# How do I get Windows to let me be on a wireless (DHCP) AND wired (static IP) network?

Tags: windows, networking

I'm trying to generate Ethernet packets to an external device with MATLAB. Right now, if I connect my computer to my external device and set my static IP to talk to the external device, my wireless connection dies.

I usually wouldn't care, except my license of MATLAB requires an active internet connection and will (a) not respond to commands that require an active license (such as trying to talk to external devices...); and (b) eventually make itself exit.

So I need a way to simultaneously keep my wifi active AND talk to my external device. (The act of talking itself is not difficult for me, or MATLAB.)

Right now my Interface Metric for the wireless NIC is set to 5, and the wired connection is set to 50. I thought that Windows should try to use the NIC with the lowest Interface Metric and only switch to a NIC with a higher one if communication can't be done with the lower NIC. I suppose this isn't the case because of the behavior I'm seeing.

Is it possible to get the behavior I want?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the static IP you used is not on the same subnet as your wireless network. It would be helpful if you can share your IP addresses used on your external device and you laptop.

Another alternative is to connect your external device, laptop and router all on the same LAN (usually means plugging both on your LAN ports of your internet gateway) and use DHCP to obtain IP address for your laptop. That way, your laptop can send packet to your external device and your MATLAB can access the internet.